# What are the "perfect" conditions for selling a small private business?

Tags: small-business, economics, selling, corporate-acquisition

As the title says. What the general opinion seems to be is that now is the best time ever to sell a small business because of low: interest rates, tax rates, and inflation, plus many large M&A firms have more capital than in previous years. Are there some additional factors that need to be considered in gauging the strength of the economy, and the overall conditions for selling a small company?

Comment: I'm concerned that this is a question about economics rather than personal finance, but it's at least plausibly relevant to people with existing sole proprietorships, so I'm not currently voting to close.

Comment: would u prefer i ask this question on the economics forum?

Comment: I'm not on the economics site so I can't say for sure it'd be on-topic there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The perfect conditions to sell a business are when it is very
  valuable (lots of profit each year) and you've lost interest in
  growing it any further.
- Also if you're in a particular industry when everyone is dying to get
  into that industry (like the dot com bubble) those are perfect
  conditions to sell.

Other things like low interest rates and excess M&A capital might contribute to *good* conditions, but the two cases above are *perfect* conditions.

Comment: You missed another perfect condition: (3) When you know your business is about to unrecoverably plummet in value, and you can sell it for higher than its current value.

Answer (score 1):

Right now is the perfect time to sell a business.

The ideal time to sell a business is when....

The stock market is hot/high (it is)
Interest rates are low (they are)
Inflation rate is low (it is)
Financing is abundant (it is)
Market is brisk (it is)
When demand is higher than supply (it is)
Buyers abound (they are)
Pricing is favorable (it is)
The company is performing well
The owner is ready

Comment: You are assuming the the market conditions in North Carolina (where you are) is the same as the market conditions in Texas (where the OP is). Sow how is the cratering Texas oil industry factor into the conditions in North Carolina?